# Removing Places from OSM

Tags: javascript, openstreetmap, google-places, removeall

Doe is exists a way to remove all the places from the OSM map? Also like shops, bars, restorations, hotels etc.

I wish to use a maps with a less info. Is it possible to do this from the original OSM server? Maybe like a option in URL or something else? I use Leaflet library for my project, maybe some option in it?

I wished to have it like in GMAPS API:

```
new google.maps.Map(map_div,{
    styles:[{
        elementType:'all',
        featureType:'poi',
        stylers:[{
            visibility:'off'
            }]
        }]});
```

Over JS or over extra URL, so or so, but without places.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The main OSM service provides only one rendering, and you can't change that rendering. Instead, you could:

- Render your own tiles - you could design them in [Tilemill](http://www.mapbox.com/tilemill/) and host them using [Tilestache](http://tilestache.org/).
- Use maps provided by a third party, such as these [Mapbox maps](http://www.mapbox.com/tilemill/gallery), or [opencyclemap](http://opencyclemap.org/), or...