# Remove amenities NAMES from openstreetmap

Tags: google-maps, openstreetmap, point-of-interest

Doe is exists a way to remove all the business from the OSM map? Also like shops, bars, restorations, hotels etc.

I wish to use a maps with a less info. Is it possible to do this from the original OSM server? Maybe like a option in URL or something else? I use Leaflet library for my project, maybe some option in it?

I wished to have it like in GMAPS API:

```
new google.maps.Map(map_div,{
  styles:[{
     elementType:'all',
     featureType:'poi',
     stylers:[{
        visibility:'off'
        }]
     }]});
```

Over JS or over extra URL, so or so, but without any business.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17531277/removing-places-from-osm

Comment: The only option besides rendering you own [tiles](https://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Tiles) is to use a tile provider without labels, for example tiles.wmflabs.org/osm-no-labels provided by Wikimedia. You can view them [here](http://mc.bbbike.org/mc/?lon=13.368594&lat=52.459748&zoom=10&num=2&mt0=osm-no-labels&mt1=mapnik) on the left side.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The short answer: No.

The map you see on openstreetmap.org is composed of static PNG images. You cannot affect how they are generated.

But then, OpenStreetMap isn't really intended to serve up maps to end-users. The project's primary product is the raw map data you can download from planet.osm.org not the map you see in your browser.

What you can do is download the raw map data and render your own map without businesses included. Using the whole planet dump is kind of overwhelming but you can download smaller extracts of the OSM data (state or in some cases city level) from several different providers. See [the OSM wiki](http://wiki.osm.org/wiki/Planet.osm#Country_and_area_extracts) for details.

Once you have the data you can render it with several different tools. I wrote a [blog post](http://ksmapper.blogspot.com/2011/08/simple-openstreetmap-tile-rendering.html) a while ago about rendering tiles using Maperitive. There is also [Tilemill](https://www.mapbox.com/tilemill/) and probably some others that I'm not thinking of right now.

Answer (score 1):

We can use maps without labels or icons, you can find many options in this site:
https://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Tile_servers

Maps used in wiki :
https://www.trailnotes.org/FetchMap/TileServeSource.html

This demo is good also:
https://wiwosm.toolforge.org/osm-on-ol/kml-on-ol.php?lat=51.52214&lon=-0.06012&zoom=10&lang=de&layers=B00TT

You can use urls as the following scripts:

```
**JS Script using Leaflet**
//No labels
var tiles = L.tileLayer('https://c.tiles.wmflabs.org/osm-no-labels/{z}/{x}/{y}.png', {
                maxZoom: 18,
                attribution: '&copy; <a href="https://www.openstreetmap.org  /copyright">OpenStreetMap</a> contributors'
        }),
            latlng = new L.LatLng(34.5, 36.55); 
//No Icons
        var roads = L.tileLayer("http://tile.memomaps.de/tilegen/{z}/{x}/{y}.png", {
           maxZoom: 20, 
        });
        var media = L.tileLayer("https://maps.wikimedia.org/osm-intl/{z}/{x}/{y}.png", {
           maxZoom: 20, 
       });
       var map = new L.Map('map', {center: latlng, zoom: 15, layers: [tiles]});

        var basemaps = { 
          'tiles':tiles, 
          'roads':roads,
          'media':media,
        };
        L.control.layers(basemaps).addTo(map);
```